# How do I modify my mouse settings with crosh/terminal in Chrome OS?

Tags: mouse, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Is it possible to modify the Chrome OS mouse speed setting using terminal/`crosh` (specifically, the `Mouse speed` setting under `Settings` → `Device` → `Mouse` (mouse must be plugged in) → `Mouse speed`)?

Reason for this is that I manage a large fleet of Pixelbooks, and I've already got a script I use to provision the environment (well, everything except the mouse settings) which I was hoping to add on to.

All pixelbooks are on latest version of Chrome OS (84.0.4147.94), so unfortunately `xset`/`inputcontrol` are no longer available :/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the mouse within crosh. Crosh does not have access to the chrome os file system. You could try to put the chromebook in developer mode and edit the mouse cursor though crosh then (you would also need to turn off rootfs verification) But that seems a little much for a mouse cursor.