# Change Trackpoint cursor speed on ChromeOS

Tags: google-chrome-os, trackpoint

On my Lenovo's Chromebook that has a Trackpoint in addition to a trackpad, on ChromeOS' setting for "Touchpad".
Changing the speed there does change the speed of touchpad, but not the Trackpoint.

How can I change the Trackpoint speed?

I'm on Lenovo C14.

Related or not, I had `Powerwash`ed this ChromeOS twice before I started noticing this issue.

---

UPDATE 20231018: Thanks for a comment @Arctiic.

> Have you checked 1) CROSH?, 2) chrome://about internal pages?, 3) chrome://flags to see if additional config access can be enabled?

1. I had no idea about `crosh`, I still don't know what to do with it. Closest related may be `tpcontrol` (ref. [krypted.com](https://krypted.com/commands/crosh-commands/)), but it doesn't seem available on my ChromeOS. Unsure though, [superuser.com#1573062](https://superuser.com/questions/1573062/how-do-i-modify-my-mouse-settings-with-crosh-terminal-in-chrome-os) reads `crosh` cannot access trackpad so if that's correct then I assume no access to track point either?
2. I cannot find something that's  relevant to trackpoint in `chrome://about`, `chrome://flags`. Do you have specific links inside of those pages in mind?

Also tried a suggestion from an old thread [groups.google.com/chromium-os-discuss/xf4kzqgQOQo](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-os-discuss/c/xf4kzqgQOQo/m/S_qCsYgzBNwJ) -- placing a conf file below on Linux using ChromeOS' developer mode, and reboot the OS. Albeit not knowing whether the conf content is appropriate for my need though, and also it's under dev mode, it doesn't seem to be taking an effect.

```
$ more /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-trackpoint.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
        MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option          "EmulateWheel"          "true"
        Option          "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
        Option          "Emulate3Buttons"       "false"
        Option          "XAxisMapping"          "6 7"
        Option          "YAxisMapping"          "4 5"
EndSection
```

---

UPDATE 2023/10/16: On another Chromebook of mine, Lenovo C13, which comes with a `Trackpoint` device as well, I do see the speed setting under "Device -> Mouse and touchpad": [image]

But on the device in question (C14) I do not see such an option.
[image]

Comment: If you can't find it under mouse settings then there isn0t such possibility.

Comment: Have you checked 1) CROSH?, 2) chrome://about internal pages?, 3) chrome://flags to see if additional config access can be enabled?

Comment: @Arctiic Thanks, I added more info in OP regarding your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Powerwash`ing ChromeOS seems to have resolved it. I now see TrackPoint option under `Settings` -> `Device` -> `Mouse and touchpad`, while so far I haven't noticed any operational regression.

For the record, ChromeOS version: 118.0.5993.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)